# ng serve fails to run after npm install

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to install and run my first Angular 6 program but after 'npm install' I'm getting this error

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ang66",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5"
  }
}
```

> ```
>  ng serve
>
>     Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
>     Error: Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
>         at _error (C:\Users\NIIT.LAP-RKT-0X52602\Desktop\prog\web\ang\ang66\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:8:11)
>         at getApiMember (C:\Users\NIIT.LAP-RKT-0X52602\Desktop\prog\web\ang\ang66\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:11:32)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NIIT.LAP-RKT-0X52602\Desktop\prog\web\ang\ang66\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:50:19)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>         at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>         at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NIIT.LAP-RKT-0X52602\Desktop\prog\web\ang\ang66\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:28:23)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
> ```

Comment: did you install angular-cli?

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli@^6

Comment: you should go to the latest version of angular-cli ( https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11084#issuecomment-458571627 )

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
npm install typescript@3.5.3
npm install  @angular/compiler@8.2.3
npm install ajv@^6.1

npm uninstall @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
```

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading @angular/cli, @angular/compiler and @angular/compiler-cli.

`npm i --save-dev @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli`